# ¿Como almaceno en la tabla una relación polimórfica?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Migración Work (He quitado Campos)

```
Schema::create('works', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 150);
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Migración Project (He quitado Campos)

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 150);
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Migración Events

```
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->time('time');
        $table->string('place', 200);
        $table->string('city', 100);
        $table->integer('eventable_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('eventable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Modelo Work y Project (Son iguales prácticamente, pongo lo importante)

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Event', 'eventable');
}
```

Modelo Event

```
public function eventable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Para insertar un nuevo evento

```
$event = new Event();
    $event->date = $request->date;
    $event->time = $request->time;
    $event->place = $request->place;
    $event->city = $request->city;
    $event->eventable_id = Aquí antes ponía el id que paso por el formulario
    $event->eventable_type = ?????
    $event->save();
```

¿Cómo puedo rellenar en automático eventable_id y eventable_type?, veo la documentación pero no lo entiendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Busco el trabajo.
$work = Work::find($id);
//Creo el evento 
$even = new Event(['date'=>$request->date, 'time'=>$request->time, 'place'=>$request->place, 'city'=>$request->city]);
//Lo asigno y guardo
$work->event()->save($even);
```

Con esto debería guardarlo todo con los campos `eventable_id` y `eventable_type` rellenados.

Comment: Lo pruebo en casa y la marco como respuesta correcta, gracias